# how to position jupyterlab log console at the side

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

In jupyterlab (using V3.2.6) you can display a "log console" by activating

```
View-> Show Log Console
```

This log console always appears at the bottom of the browser tab and therefore takes up valuable vertical space, if you resize it to show more than a few lines.

Is there a way to position the log console at the side (e.g. to the right) of the main notebook window in order to have full vertical space in both notebook and log console?